# Как использовать gulp-imagemin и не столкнутся с ошибкой cлишком длинный путь к источнику

Tags: windows, node.js, windows-8, npm

**Windows 8.1**

```
npm install **gulp-imagemin**
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`C:\w\WebStrom\1_mcheck\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-jpegtran\node_modules\jpegtran-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\download\node_modules\gulp-decompress\node_modules\decompress\node_modules\decompress-tar\node_modules\tar-stream\node_modules\end-of-stream\node_modules\once\node_modules\wrappy\package.json`

1. Удалить нельзя,переместить,скопировать - тоже. Что делать? Мне нужно удалить эту папку с этого компа.
2. Как использовать **gulp-imagemin** и не столкнутся с этой проблемой снова?

*P.S. на странице Задать вопрос в поле Тема maxlength="300", а ограничение длины заголовка - 150. Неудобно*

Comment: 1. вероятно, метки поставлены неправильно: должна быть метка [tag:windows]. 2. посмотрите здесь: http://superuser.com/q/78434/454489

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас дополню свой вопрос

Comment: прошу прощения за плохую формулировку: я подразумевал, что ни к node.js, ни к npm ошибка при удалении файлов с длинными именами не имеет отношения.

Comment: Ответ на Ваш вопрос есть в документации.

Comment: Ссылку, пожалуйста.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да это я сам вопрос неправильно поставил.. На изначальный вопрос вы дали вполне исчерпывающий ответ

Comment: @Darth, `shatal` не получит оповещения о вашей просьбе: вы не упомянули его имя.